# How do I read in a 16bit TIFF into R and preserve pixel intensities, so that I can use it as a labelled object mask using the EBImage package?

Tags: r

I have a 16-bit grayscale image object mask where each object is a single grayscale value from 1 to 5750 (the number of objects). When I read it with the EBImage package, pixel values drop to below 1:

```
objectMask <- readImage("/Volumes/myHD/objectMask.tiff")
range(objectMask@.Data)
[1] 0.00000000 0.08792248
```

I intend to treat this image as if it were a labelled image similar to the output of the bwlabel {EBImage} function.
objectMask is storage.mode:double while bwlabel(objectMask) is storage.mode:integer. I don't know if this is a problem, but if I manually change it to integer

```
storage.mode(objectMask) <- "integer"
```

all of the pixel values become 0, so clearly the problem is that it is being rescaled somehow when I read it in. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of EBImage, "readImage loads all images from the files vector and returns them stacked into a single Image object containing an array of doubles ranging from 0 (black) to 1 (white)."

The reason all of the values are becoming 0 when you change the storage mode to integer is because they are all being rounded up to the closest integer.

Therefore, you first need to undo the rescaling introduced by the readImage function, and then change the storage type to integer:

```
objectMask <- readImage("/Volumes/myHD/objectMask.tiff")
objectMask@.Data <- objectMask@.Data * 5750
storage.mode(objectMask) <- "integer"
```

**Edit with alternative solution**

An alternative solution, covering the problem caused by the fact that the conversion to integers merges some of the objects.

First, we create a factor with each level representing one of the objects:

```
factorData <- factor(objectMask@.Data, levels=c(0, unique(as.vector(objectMask@.Data[objectMask@.Data>0]))))
```

Note that the levels are defined with 0 as the first level, so that the pixels with value of 0 will be assigned level 1.

We then reassign the values of objectMask@.Data:

```
objectMask@.Data=matrix(as.integer(factorData)-1, nrow=nrow(objectMask@.Data))
```

Note the following:

- We subtract 1 from the result of converting the factors to integers, so that background pixels will get again a value of 0
- The dimensions of the image are preserved by setting `nrow=nrow(objectMask@.Data)`

Comment: Thanks. This gets me closer but doesn't quite work, because the pixel values aren't getting rescaled from 0-1 as documentation suggests: `range(objectMask@.Data)
[1] 0.00000000 0.08792248`  Also peculiar is that most pixels should be black (background), but apparently every pixel has a unique value: `length(unique(objectMask@.Data))
[1] 2002000` This is a 1001 x 2000 pixel image.

Comment: I also tried to scale it myself to 1 `objectMask@.Data <- nucMask@.Data * 5750 * (1/max(objectMask@.Data))`  but not  not all objects got separated: `max(bwlabel(objectMask)) [1] 3820`

Comment: There is several separate issues going on here. Firstly, `unique(objectMask@.Data)` returns the number of unique rows in the matrix, not the number of unique elements. You can use `unique(as.vector(objectMask@.Data))` to verify the number of objects. If not all objects got separated, a workaround would be to first convert the rescaled data to a factor, and then assign new values based on this: `factorData = factor(objectMask@.Data, levels=unique(as.vector(objectMask@.Data)))`, then we convert the data to integer: `objectMask@.Data=matrix(as.integer(factorData)-1, nrow=nrow(objectMask@.Data))`

Comment: Note that you might need to round up the rescaled data before converting to factors to account for inequality of the double values. Also, note that you need to subtract 1 to the integer values derived from the factor to have a value of 0 for the background. This is therefore assuming that the first value (the top left pixel) in the rescaled data will not be part of an object, and therefore its value will be 0. If this is not the case, factorData should be calculated as `factorData = factor(objectMask@.Data, levels=c(0, unique(as.vector(objectMask@.Data[objectMask@.Data>0]))))`